# Error message when trying to execute exit() in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
def calculate():
    while True:
            operator = input("What operator do you wanna use(*,/,+,-)? ")
            possible_op = "+-*/"

            if operator not in possible_op:
                continue
            try:
                number_1 = float(input("What is your first number? "))
                number_2 = float(input("What is your second number? "))
            except ValueError:
                continue
        
            if operator == "+":
                print(number_1 + number_2) 
            elif operator == "-":
                print(number_1 - number_2) 
            elif operator == "*":
                print(number_1 *  number_2) 
            elif operator == "/":
                print(number_1 / number_2) 


            try:
                print("Do you wanna calculate again? ")
                answer = input("(Y/N) ").lower()
                possible_answers = ["y", "n"]
                if answer == "y":
                    return calculate()
                elif answer == "n":
                    exit()
            except input != possible_answers: 
                print("Wrong Input")
                continue 

calculate()
```

When I tried to open my script in Microsoft VS Code, I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\Projects\VsCode\calculator\calculator_school.py", line 31, in calculate
    exit()
  File "D:\Schule\Phyton\lib\_sitebuiltins.py", line 26, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\Projects\VsCode\calculator\calculator_school.py", line 36, in <module>
    calculate()
  File "e:\Python\Projects\VsCode\calculator\calculator_school.py", line 32, in calculate
    except input != possible_answers:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

When I open it in my file explorer, the script closes itself in Cmd as it should. But in VS Code it just won't. Why is that?

Comment: you need to call `sys.exit()`

Comment: Look how VSCode launch your program and how you launch it manually, you maybe have 2 version of python installed. Moreover VSCode launch the program from the opened folder, if you launch it manually, you probably do it from the first parent directory of your program, it can cause bugs sometimes

Comment: `except input != possible_answers` doesn't make sense. `except` needs to specify a type of exception, not a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the script even with a break in this case.
you're inside a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit without using try except statement. Try this:

```
def calculate():
  while True:
    operator = input("What operator do you wanna use(*,/,+,-)? ")
    possible_op = "+-*/"

    if operator not in possible_op:
      continue
    try:
      number_1 = float(input("What is your first number? "))
      number_2 = float(input("What is your second number? "))
    except ValueError:
      continue

    if operator == "+":
      print(number_1 + number_2) 
    elif operator == "-":
      print(number_1 - number_2) 
    elif operator == "*":
      print(number_1 *  number_2) 
    elif operator == "/":
      print(number_1 / number_2) 
    while True:
      print("Do you wanna calculate again? ")
      answer = input("(Y/N) ").lower()
      if answer == "y":
        return calculate()
      elif answer == "n":
        quit()
      else: 
        print("Wrong Input")
        continue 
calculate()
```